# Get public array values with Web3py

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

Is there a way to get `poolInfo[0]` public array element value (represented by Struct) via call request by Web3py library (without writing getter function)?

Contract snippet:

```
struct PoolInfo {
        uint256 id;
        address poolAddress;
        uint256 poolType;
        address lpToken;
        address Rewards;
        uint256 FeePercentage;
        bool pauseDeposit;
        address[] RewardTokens;
    }

PoolInfo[] public poolInfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
pool_info = contract.functions.poolInfo(0).call()
print(pool_info) # You will get a tuple representing your object
```

Contract is an object that was created from **w3.eth.contract**